# HAProxy URL redirection

Tags: redirect, rewrite, haproxy, url

I have a goal to redirect some URLs into one.
I mean this is the destination url: https://application.company.com

I want to redirect:
http://company.com
https://company.com
https://application.company.com
http://application.company.com
http://www.application.company.com
https://www.application.company.com

to that destination URL
What would be the martest to do in HAProxy?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to this amazing site, you could try to browse previous topics about haproxy, because I am sure this question has been asked many times

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map.

```
company.com                 application.company.com
www.application.company.com application.company.com
```

haproxy conf untested

```
listen redirector
  bind :::80

  http-request redirect code 301 location https://application.company.com !{ ssl_fc }
  http-request redirect code 301 location https://%[req.hdr(host),lower,map(domain.map)]
```